# Remote wipe of application data in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4

I am working on an enterprise application, where the client has the requirement of wiping all the data stored by the application, from the device, remotely. That is, in the case when a user reports a lost device.

If we forget about the service side implementation of it, is it even possible to do a remote wipe of data stored in application sandbox. What about deleting files present in the application resources like sqllite files and certificates?

I was browsing the net for it and came along [this site](http://www.good.com/iphone/) which claims to do so in their product.

If it can be done, how should we approach this problem?

Remote wipe feature has been added by Apple in iOS 4.2 onwards using mobile me. I don't think they are doing this through remote notifications. In that case there wouldn't be any sure shot guarantee, that the data is deleted from the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to encrypt the data on the iPhones disk and only decrypt it in memory (since iOS 4 there is a similar mechanism built in).
Before you let the user use the data, you ask a server if the iPhone is allowed to encrypt the data (a even better approach would be that the server gives the iPhone the key to decrypt the data, so a attacker won't find it in code). If the server denies the request, the App wipes all the stored data and you are done.

This of course only works when your app is allowed to require a internet connection (or at least a connection to the local intranet where it can communicate with the server)

Comment: Your solution seems to be the most logical approach. However the link I shared in my question(about the good for enterprise application) says that "Delete the Good application and encrypted data if phone is lost or stolen—or wipe the entire device in situations that require it". I am wondering that if they are able to delete the whole application, there must be a way to do that.

Comment: @Vin: I'm not sure how they did it, my guess would be that they use some kind of jailbreak. While it is possible to delete a running binary on OS X (and thus I guess also on iOS), the binary itself is in a shielded folder and the sandbox will stop you. Remotely killing the app while it doesn't run would be possible through a running daemon, I guess your best bet would be mobile substrate (Jailbreak). But well, a Jailbreak might not be the solution you want, but as its "just" a enterprise app it would be possible.

Comment: I don't think they are using Jailbreak. The app is freely available in the appstore. Search Good for enterprise.

Comment: @Vin: Oh, thats interesting. Because you can't remove your own binary as app (as well as any other binary) and to perform any action your app has to run. I really have no idea how that would be possible at all without violating a App Store rule. Are you sure that they wipe the data immediately without having something running?

Comment: I haven't used the app(just downloaded it), but the site says "Delete the Good application and encrypted data if phone is lost or stolen—or wipe the entire device in situations that require it". How can this be done by a third party app?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that (short of requiring the user to jailbreak), that application leaves a stub of itself that doesn't do anything, after deleting all the data from the app. And it almost certainly uses remote notifications to do it, if it's triggered from off the device.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with Dan, that would be the only way it could work in a "legal" way.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I don't think there's any other possible way. I would accept this answer and upvote Dan's answer and comments :)

Comment: Just found this link http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/integration/mdm/  .Seems like remote wipe is done using a MDM(Mobile Device Management Server)

Comment: @Vin: Thanks for sharing the link, as far as I can see this is really done via an external server, and not something an app in the app store can enable.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think to satisfy that requirement is to set up remote notifications, and have a notification handler in the app turf the sensitive data when fired. That's not the best approach (I rather like some of the other suggestions in this thread), but in sheer terms of the requirement, Apple Remote Notifications seem like the only way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan. But like I mentioned in comment to JustSid's answer, how is a third party app, available in the app store do that and much more?

Comment: It can't be. Literally, the things you would need to be able to get at aren't available to you on a non-jailbroken device. I can't fathom that they actually mean what they seem to be claiming without requiring the user to jailbreak. Deleting data is one thing. Removing the whole app from within the app? Can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should strore all the data you want to wipe in Documents folder, and then wipe it if needed

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the items stored in sqlite or documents folder on getting some notification. But this is possible only when you open the application and get the notification.
I can give one example:
When **application opens** the user will get some message say from your local server(may be on login or on loading your first screen).
when you get this message delete the data from sqlite or documents folder which ever you have used.

However in the above case it is required that application is opened. If you need data to be deleted even if application is not launched, may be you need to use push notification

Comment: The case is, if the device has been stolen, there is a chance that the new user would not launch the app on receiving the notifications.

Comment: yes thats correct. But deletion can happen only launching or else how will the app know that device is stolen and the data should be deleted. You can introduce a login screen for your app. In this case your application will be secured.

Answer (score 0):

The web side you mention is talking about wiping mail and calendar data.

There is the MobileMe service that lets you wipe a phone completely, assuming you have push enabled ([details](http://www.macworld.com/article/141605/2009/07/remotewipe.html)).

Then again if somebody "finds" the phone and is clever enough to disable push and `Find My iPhone` in Settings before the remote wipe command is issued they could get away with your data. It is enough the scare away the petty phone thief but not the one who is after your data.

An app can remove its own data. But it can do so only while active (foreground or background). Again it becomes a timing problem of you telling the app to delete what needs to be deleted before somebody not authorized can extract it.

Answer (score -1):

Store everything in the Documents folder. then use the code on this thread to delete everything

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *directoryContents = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    for (NSString *path in directoryContents) {

        if([path isEqualToString:@"cache.db"]) { 
            //dont delete db

        }
        else {
            NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];

            //NSLog(myFilePath);

            BOOL removeSuccess = [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:&error];
            if (!removeSuccess) {
                //handle errors?
                NSLog(@"Not deleted: %@ %@", path, [error userInfo]);

            }

        }


    }

} else {
    // Error handling
    //...
}
```

[Deleting all the files in the iPhone sandbox (documents folder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iphone-sandbox-documents-folder)

Comment: I saw your question. The problem here is that, some files like sqlite db are present in the resources folder of the app also(before they are copied to documents folder). What about these files?