# Anyway to clear <application_home>/Documents folder during update process for iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I have had an existing iOS iPhone app in the app store for the past several months (v1.0). Everything on that app worked just fine.

I have been spending the past several weeks creating a new version of the app. I thoroughly tested the app before submitting it to Apple for an update.

Apple approved the update (v1.1) and the app works just fine on a first-time install. The issue I run into is that if you are updating from a previous version, the new version downloads, but when you open it up, the app is broken. In fact, it appears to be a cached version of the old app, with blank screens and missing icons.

Unfortunately, I did not perform an update scenario test prior to sending the app in for review.

Since my app's code base has changed significantly, it appears as if there are some leftover cached files inside of the iPhone app's /Documents directory
from the previous version of my app that are at fault.

I am trying to prepare an update/fix that detects the presence of the old cache files in /Documents/ and /Library/ and remove them.
Thus treating the app as a new install, rather than trying to merge code from the previous versions cache.

Anyways, I was wondering if other folks have run into this issue, and if there are any tips on how I should proceed.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting all the files in the iPhone sandbox (documents folder)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iphone-sandbox-documents-folder)

Answer (score 1):

So, here i give the link for delete the all data from the document directory their for the blowing code may be help to improve your application version.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0)
{
  NSLog(@"Path: %@", [paths objectAtIndex:0]);

  NSError *error = nil;
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  // Remove Documents directory and all the files
  BOOL deleted = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:&error];

  if (deleted != YES || error != nil)
  {
    // Deal with the error...
  }

}
```