# Do you need to delete imported files from Documents/Inbox?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I've got an iOS app that imported files from an email attachment.
I've noticed that once i'm finished with it it places the imported file into Documents/Inbox.

Should my app be deleting these files or does the OS eventually get around to clearing them out?

if so, how? i've tried:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[self.url path] error:nil];
```

However it doesn't seem to reference the file in the inbox, even though self.url is the correct path to my import file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System does not clear imported files, so you should clear them manually when it is necessary, but not to delete the Documents directory.

How to clear the `NSDocumentsDirectory` you can find **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iphone-sandbox-documents-folder)**

If you want to delete files from the inbox use the same code adding

```
...
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Inbox", documentsDirectory ];
NSArray *directoryContents = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:&error];
...
```

Read the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

From apple doc:

> Use this directory to access files that your app was asked to open by
>   outside entities. Specifically, the Mail program places email
>   attachments associated with your app in this directory; document
>   interaction controllers may also place files in it.
>
> Your app can read and delete files in this directory but cannot create new files or write to existing files. If the user tries to edit
>   a file in this directory, your app must silently move it out of the
>   directory before making any changes.
>
> The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

Comment: this doesn't clear the Inbox. this Inbox folder seems to be a special folder. its created by the system, not my app. i can't delete it using this method.