# Move Document/Inbox file to another location - Xcode 7, Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7, documents, inbox

I have a file that is in my `Documents/Inbox` and is shown in my `Print` log:

> File:
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5388031B-48B5-48D6-8299-B3FEDC1D7F45/Documents/Inbox/Pizza-6.pdf

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213226/do-you-need-to-delete-imported-files-from-documents-inbox) and saw a way to delete files, but I want to move them out of the `Inbox` folder to another folder I want to create.  How would I do this?  I can't find anything for iOS and Swift 2. Thank you.

Comment: "for Xcode 7"?  Xcode is an IDE.  Did you mean for iOS using Swift?  Anyway I expect it will involve `NSFileManager`, so start with a search for "iOS move file" and "nsfilemanager move file".  You'll then need to convert the solution from Objective-C to Swift yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my information.  I'm new to programming so trying to convert Objective-C to Swift is hard for me.  I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    // MOVING AND SAVING INCOMING PDF TO FILE MANAGER FROM INBOX

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let docsDirURL = try! filemgr.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)

    // Create a new folder in the directory named "Recipes"
    print("Creating new folder...")
    let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
    let newPath = documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Recipes")
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(newPath.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }

    // Then check if the Recipes directory exists. If not, create it
    let recipesURL = docsDirURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Recipes")
    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(docsDirURL.path!) {
        do {
            try filemgr.createDirectoryAtURL(recipesURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            print("Directory created at: \(recipesURL)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    // Move file from Inbox to Recipes Folder
    let incomingFileName = incomingFileTransfer.lastPathComponent!
    let startingURL = incomingFileTransfer
    let savePDFURL = recipesURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(incomingFileName)

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(savePDFURL.path!) {
        do {
            try filemgr.moveItemAtURL(startingURL, toURL: savePDFURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unable to move file \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
```