# How do I delete files in the Documents folder

Tags: ios, itunes, delete-file, file-sharing

Okay, I'm still not a wiz a Xcode, but I have a solid understanding now, now I have a problem and I'm hoping I'll be able to get a "Problem, meet solution" answer.

Situation: I've implemented the "kqueue" to monitor my Documents folder and I've been able to present them in the UITableViewController.  But what I need to be capable of is being able to delete these files when the user needs to.  I have my editing button (that to me, magically turns to "Done" when I'm editing and the flags pop up and what not), and I can remove them from my list.  But when I close (completely from the Multitasking UI) or when I add a new file to the File Sharing window via iTunes, the files I thought were deleted, reappear.

So, how do I delete the files from the Documents folder rather than hiding them (which I assume is what happened)?

Next, where do I implement them, do I need to add a new objective-c class, or can I work of the DirectoryWatcher class?

I hope I've been as detailed as I can be, but if I haven't please feel free to leave a comment because I need resolution to this soon (my developers program ends in 40 days).

Comment: See `NSFileManager`. It has methods for copying, moving, and deleting files.

Comment: Why do you need this resolved soon? Just renew your developer program. You have to anyway if you put your app in the store. If your program expires, Apple will take all of your app store apps off the market.

Comment: See this [Deleting all the files in the iPhone sandbox (documents folder)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iphone-sandbox-documents-folder)

Comment: Did you implement the - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method ?. You should put the file deletion code inside this method.

Comment: @maddy: Because I don't have enough disposable money at the moment to renew.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The link didn't really help, sorry.

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama: Yes, but I think it only removes the index path established between the cell and the file, then when the directory changes, the view is updated to reflect the contents.