# Is there a way to remove all the data/caches when upgrading app from AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

Small percentage of my user get ugly bug related to WKWebView when updating to the latest version of my app from AppStore. 
The bug goes away when the app is removed and installed all over again. 
Is there a way to remove old data/caches during the upgrade?

Comment: "old code"?  You mean "old data", right?

Comment: You mean user-saved data?

Comment: I have no idea what is this old thing is. I didn't write the old code and don't have it. Maybe there are some caches or something...

Comment: You have no idea whether you are talking about data or code?

Comment: So you're saying you did not write the old version's code?

Comment: I want to remove everything! All caches, all everything. On upgrade, I want the app to be installed from scratch. How do I do it?

Comment: You can do that yourself.  Store the current app version in user defaults and when it changes you can delete all data.  Then store the new version of the app in user defaults.  This is non-standard behaviour so you'll have to code it yourself.

Comment: Look, if you do not react to questions we ask you this won't work. Again, did you write the app's current version?

Comment: If you do not have old code,I think clear all saved data when user first launch your new version app may be an option.

Comment: @Leo , how do I do it?

Comment: @LinusG. It won't work if you won't read the answers to your questions. I wrote before - I wrote the current version. Not the previous one

Comment: @Luda You may refer to this link. Just clear the sandbox to the default state of an app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iphone-sandbox-documents-folder

Comment: Sorry, skipped that apparently, @Luda

Answer (score 0):

All the code is removed when you update an app. If your app changes how it uses for example data that isn't removed, such as NSUserDefaults you have to add logic in your code to handle "old" data being present.

Comment: I want to remove everything! All caches, all everything. On upgrade, I want the app to be installed from scratch. How do I do it?

Comment: @LinusG. Yes, I know. That's exactly what I meant. Code is removed. Data is not.

Comment: Oh ok, well I think she is confused but means data.

Comment: @Luda You have to figure out what data that's causing the bug and write code that works around the possibility of data that is incompatible with your new version.

Comment: I'd be careful with your emphasis on the word 'is'... Changed it for you ;)

Comment: @LinusG. Good point. I see that my answer might seem to say that some data isn't removed. I'll update my answer!

Comment: That wasn't my point, I meant the current political situation is a bit difficult and you should not stress the word 'is' using capitals. :D

Comment: @LinusG. Haha. Ah, ok :)

Comment: @trojanfoe, how do I remove everything?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but here is two possible approaches:

#### 1.

When your app loads up, in AppDelegate check for saved data inside the `didLaunchWithOptions()`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let data = userDefaults.valueForKey("<yourKey>") {
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("<yourKey>")
    }
    
    return true
}
```

You'll have to insert the keys used in your application for saving stuff instead of `<yourKey>`, of course.

#### 2.

You could also try the following code, that will erase all the contents of NSUserDefaults, which will make the key unnecessary:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.ma‌​inBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: But does it erase the caches as well?

Comment: Do you have the keys? Then it will.

Comment: @Luda Depends on what you mean by "caches". Are we talking about NSUserDefault here or is there other data in the app that might cause the bug?

Comment: I think in my case the second point is enough for removing everything from NSUserDefaults. But what about that? Should that also be done? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iph%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bone-sandbox-documents-folder

Comment: Looks a good approach as well. You should try it. Btw, are you able to reproduce the bug?